# Testing iPhone app with Valgrind

Tags: iphone, debugging, valgrind

I have terrific bug "object was modified after being freed", so I tend to take valgrind. After successfull installation from their svn,  doing little trick from here:

http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Simulator_Valgrind.20081224.html

and changing path to valgrind with my one, I get "Debugger terminated." with gdb log:

[Session started at 2010-08-03 10:47:25 +0500.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1469) (Wed May  5 04:36:56 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 17763.
warning: Could not remove breakpoint at "0x8fe0b830".
Cannot remove breakpoints because program is no longer writable.
It might be running in another process.
Further execution is probably impossible.
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

Error calling thread_get_state for float registers for thread 0x5123lx1243^error,msg="Not safe to call dlopen at this time."

Please advise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do Run instead of Debug.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but what dose the mean "Do Run instead of Debug" BTW, I use Xcode 4.3

Comment: @user392412 Not sure how to do it in the new versions of Xcode, but it now has a pretty good set of tools making Valgrind less useful.